# Conjugacy Classes of subgroups in GL(n,p)

Tags: group-theory

What is the conjugacy class of subgroups of order $p$ in $GL(n,p)$? (Are all subgroups of order $p$ conjugate in $GL(n,p)$?)

Comment: You mean "What are the conjugacy classes of subgroups of order $p$ in $GL(n,p)$?

Comment: Take a look at the possible subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ fixed by an element of order $p$ in $\mathrm{GL}(n, p)$. Do they all have the same dimension?

Comment: @Alex: Should (s)he compute the order of $\mathrm{GL}(n, p)$ just to get to know the group, or does the order of the group help in any way for the question?

Comment: @Alex: I'm very curious about this. How does the order help considering that there is also a cyclic group of the same order?

Comment: @jug I'm sorry, I was oversimplifying things. Please ignore my comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every subgroup of order p in GL(n,p) is conjugate to a subgroup generated by a matrix in Frobenius normal form.  Such a matrix is a direct sum of [companion matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomials (x−1)<sup>k</sup> where 1 ≤ k ≤ p, and is determined up to conjugacy by the [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of n defined by 1 ≤ k<sub>1</sub> ≤ k<sub>2</sub> ≤ … ≤ k<sub>m</sub> ≤ p where n = k<sub>1</sub> + k<sub>2</sub> + … + k<sub>m</sub> and all such partitions other than 1 ≤ 1 ≤ … ≤ 1 define subgroups of order p (k<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>2</sub> = … = k<sub>n</sub> = 1 defines the trivial subgroup).

These k<sub>i</sub> are calculated from the subgroup by considering the dimensions of subspaces fixed by the subgroup (eigenspaces of eigenvalue 1) and the associated generalized eigenspaces (nullspaces of those polynomials (x−1)<sup>k</sup>), so this is just a more detailed version of @jug's comment.

If we let I(n,p) be the number of conjugacy classes of subgroups of GL(n,p) of order p, then we have the bijective but slightly messy formula:

> I(n,p) = number of partitions (disregarding order) of n into positive integers no greater than p.
>   In particular, **no**, GL(n,p) contains non-conjugate subgroups of order p as soon as n ≥ 3 if p is odd, and as soon as n ≥ 4 if p = 2.

For p = 2, one gets the simple formula I(n,2) = floor(n/2).

I believe this is also equal to NrPartitions(n+p,p)−1, the number of partitions of n+p into at most p things (and subtracting one to remove the trivial subgroup).  This should follow by dual Young tableaux or otherwise by general combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

*(Same as Jack's, different normal form!)*

If $A\in\operatorname{GL}(n,p)$ has order $p$, then $A^p-I=0$. It follows that $A$ satisfies the polynomial $X^p-1$, so the minimal polynomial $m_A$ divides $X^p-1=(X-1)^p$. Since every eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of $m_A$, we conclude that the only eigenvalue of $A$ (in any algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$), is $1$.

It follows at once that both the Jordan form $J$ of $A$ and a matrix conjugating $A$ to $J$ are in fact both elements of $\operatorname{GL}(n,p)$. If we want to count the elements of $\{A\in\operatorname{GL}(n,p):A^p=I\}$ up to conjugation in $\operatorname{GL}(n,p)$, then, it is enough to count the conjugacy classes of matrices of $\operatorname{GL}(n,p)$ in Jordan canonical form with minimal polynomial dividing $(X-1)^p$.

This is a pretty simple excercise. The answer is: the number of partitions of $n$ with parts not larger than $p$.

**Hmm, this is counting conjugacy classes of matrices and not of subgroups...***

Comment: In general conjugacy classes of elements and conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups are similar (the latter are called **rational** conjugacy classes).  For GL (and p-elements) and "big" groups (like symmetric groups) they are the same.  In other words, all the generators of a subgroup of order p have the same generalized eigenspaces, so are all conjugate, so every conjugacy class (of elements of order p) is rational.